# How to crop an image while uploading?

Tags: php, image, crop

I am doing an social networking project ,where i have an option to add/edit photos ,When user clicks the button the image will be uploaded to the database and it will be updated...is it possible to crop the image before it is saved to the database.

Comment: If you want to crop server side before you save the file you can create a copy of the image using the GD image library http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php the function that will do the cropping is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply call this function ..with param source ,destination and size what u want :)

```
function cropImage($source,$dest,$whsize) {

                $size = getimagesize($source);
                $w = $size[0];
                $h = $size[1];
                $xratio=$w/$whsize;
                $yratio=$h/$whsize;

                if($xratio > $yratio)$multiplier=$xratio;
                else $multiplier=$yratio;

                $nw=$w/$multiplier;
                $nh=$h/$multiplier;
                switch($size[2]) {
                    case '1':
                    $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                    break;
                    case '2':
                    $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                    break;
                    case '3':
                    $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                    break;
                }

                $dimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);

                $wm = $w/$nw;
                $hm = $h/$nh;

                $h_height = $nh/2;
                $w_height = $nw/2;

                if($w> $h) {

                    $adjusted_width = $w / $hm;
                    $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
                    $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;

                    imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,-$int_width,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$w,$h);

                } elseif(($w <$h) || ($w == $h)) {

                    $adjusted_height = $h / $wm;
                    $half_height = $adjusted_height / 2;
                    $int_height = $half_height - $h_height;

                    imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,0,-$int_height,0,0,$nw,$adjusted_height,$w,$h);

                } else {
                    imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,0,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
                }
             $dest=$dest.'jpeg';
                imagejpeg($dimg,$dest,100);
        }
```

Comment: this is how the image will be cropped

Answer (score 3):

On the client side I'd recommend [JCrop](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, move the file out of the uploads directory and into a temp directory somewhere, store that location in their session, then display it back to them and let them crop it before you move it to your production area and insert it into the database.