# How to crop the uploaded image

Tags: jquery, crop

By using the below code i have uploaded an image and generate progress bar while uploading.Now i need to crop a particular section from that uploaded image  and have to display the cropped section in a seperate div. Reference link:[Html file upload](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/3/index.html)

Html:

```
<body>
<div>
<h2 class="">Upload a Profile Image</h2>
<div class="control-group">
  <form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
      <div>
        <div id="filedrag"><img src="images/profile_imgholder.png" alt=""/><br/>
          Drop a photo to upload here<br/>
          or</div>
        <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple/>
      </div>
      <div id="submitbutton">
        <button type="submit">Upload Files</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div id="progress"> </div>
  <div id="messages"> </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/filedrag.js"></script>
</body>
```

jquery

```
/*
filedrag.js - HTML5 File Drag & Drop demonstration
Featured on SitePoint.com
Developed by Craig Buckler (@craigbuckler) of OptimalWorks.net
*/
(function() {

    // getElementById
    function $id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }


    // output information
    function Output(msg) {
        var m = $id("messages");
        m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
    }


    // file drag hover
    function FileDragHover(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
    }


    // file selection
    function FileSelectHandler(e) {

        // cancel event and hover styling
        FileDragHover(e);

        // fetch FileList object
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        // process all File objects
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            ParseFile(f);
            UploadFile(f);
        }

    }


    // output file information
    function ParseFile(file) {

        // display an image
        if (file.type.indexOf("image") == 0) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                Output(

                    '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" />'
                );
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        // display text
        if (file.type.indexOf("text") == 0) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                Output(
                    "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong></p><pre>" +
                    e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") +
                    "</pre>"
                );
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }

    }


    // upload JPEG files
    function UploadFile(file) {

        // following line is not necessary: prevents running on SitePoint servers
        if (location.host.indexOf("sitepointstatic") >= 0) return

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.upload && file.type == "image/jpeg" && file.size <= $id("MAX_FILE_SIZE").value) {

            // create progress bar
            var o = $id("progress");
            var progress = o.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
            /*progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode("upload " + file.name));*/


            // progress bar
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
                progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
            }, false);

            // file received/failed
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
                }
            };

            // start upload
            xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
            xhr.send(file);

        }

    }


    // initialize
    function Init() {

        var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
            filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
            submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

        // file select
        fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

        // is XHR2 available?
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.upload) {

            // file drop
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
            filedrag.style.display = "block";

            // remove submit button
            submitbutton.style.display = "none";
        }

    }

    // call initialization file
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        Init();
    }


})();
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263966/how-to-crop-an-image-while-uploading?rq=1

Comment: Hi i have tried to implement this code but it shows code hinting error.can u please show the crop implementation in fiddle..

Comment: What do you mean by "code hinting error?"  Please post the error message.

Comment: I am getting the error in  this line } elseif(($w <$h) || ($w == $h)) {.Even all braces are closed properly i am getting the error in this line in my dreamweaver as There is a syntax error code hinting may not work until you fix the error.

Comment: The code `} elseif(($w <$h) || ($w == $h)) {` doesn't appear in the code you pasted above.  That looks like PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: } elseif(($w <$h) || ($w == $h)) {  It is a line from the crop image code,which i have tried to implement from your reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263966/how-to-crop-an-image-while-uploading?rq=1.I